# How might I add an image behind a gradient?

Tags: css, background, linear-gradients

Where both would separate together?

After the play button is clicked, the gradient separates.

I want to place an image behind the fence gradient where both would separate together after the play button is clicked.

code:

```js
const manageCover = (function makeManageCover() {

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function hide(el) {
    el.classList.add("hide");
  }

  function openCurtain(cover) {
    hide(cover);
    const curtain = document.querySelector(".curtain");
    curtain.classList.add("slide");
    return curtain;
  }

  function showVideo(curtain) {
    const thewrap = curtain.parentElement.querySelector(".wrap");
    show(thewrap);
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    const curtain = openCurtain(cover);
    showVideo(curtain);
    cover.dispatchEvent(new Event("afterClick"));
  }

  function init(callback) {
    const cover = document.querySelector(".play");
    cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
    cover.addEventListener("afterClick", callback);
  }

  return {
    init
  };
}());

const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {
  let player;

  function loadIframeScript() {
    const tag = document.createElement("script");
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
  }

  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    const cover = document.querySelector(".play");
    const wrapper = cover.parentElement;
    const frameContainer = wrapper.querySelector(".video");
    addPlayer(frameContainer);
  }

  function onPlayerReady() {
    player.setVolume(100);
  }

  function addPlayer(video) {
    const options = {
      height: 360,
      host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
      videoId: video.dataset.id,
      width: 640
    };
    options.playerVars = {
      autoplay: 0,
      cc_load_policy: 0,
      controls: 1,
      disablekb: 1,
      fs: 0,
      iv_load_policy: 3,
      rel: 0
    };
    options.events = {
      "onReady": onPlayerReady
    };

    options.playerVars.loop = 1;
    options.playerVars.playlist = video.dataset.id;
    player = new YT.Player(video, options);
  }

  function play() {
    if (player && player.playVideo) {
      player.playVideo();
    }
  }

  function init() {
    player = null;
    loadIframeScript();
    window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = onYouTubeIframeAPIReady;
    return play;
  }

  return {
    init,
    play
  };
}());
manageCover.init(videoPlayer.init());
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(0, 0, 0) 0px, rgb(0, 0, 0) 10px, transparent 10px, transparent 11px), repeating-linear-gradient(22.5deg, rgb(0, 0, 0) 0px, rgb(0, 0, 0) 10px, transparent 10px, transparent 11px), linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(0, 89, 221), rgb(0, 89, 221), rgb(0, 89, 221), rgb(0, 89, 221), rgb(0, 89, 221));
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.curtain {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 640px;
  border: 21px solid;
  border-radius: 3.2px;
  border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
  position: relative;
}

.curtain::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  right: -2px;
  bottom: -2px;
  background: #0a0a0a;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
}

.curtain::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  outline: 1px solid #333;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.curtain.slide::after {
  outline: 1px solid #0059dd;
  transition: outline 2s ease-in;
  /*  add this */
  /*background-image: none;*/
}

.ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: fade 3s ease-in 0s forwards;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

iframe {
  user-select: none;
}

.panel-left,
.panel-right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0%;
  transition: all 8s ease;
  transition-delay: 4s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-left {
  left: 0;
}

.panel-right {
  right: 0;
}


/*.panel-left::before,
.panel-right::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  pointer-events: none;
}*/

.panel-left::before,
.panel-right::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 7px, red 7px, red 7.5px, transparent 7.5px, transparent 10px), linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent, transparent 7px, red 7px, red 7.5px, transparent 7.5px, transparent 10px);
  background-size: 10px 10px;
  /* filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px #000);*/
  pointer-events: none;
}

.panel-right::before {
  left: -100%;
}

.curtain.slide .panel-left {
  transform: translateX(calc(-100% - 1px));
}

.curtain.slide .panel-right {
  transform: translateX(calc(100% + 1px));
}

.play {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 9px solid;
  background: transparent;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px #000000b3);
  animation: rotate 700ms linear forwards;
  border-color: red transparent red transparent;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
  color: #303030;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  99.9% {
    border-color: red transparent red transparent;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    border-color: blue;
  }
}

.play::before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 27px solid;
  transform: translateX(4px);
  animation: triangle 700ms linear forwards;
}

@keyframes triangle {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  99.9% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    border-left-color: blue;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.play:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(43, 179, 20, 0.5);
}

.play:focus {
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.exit {
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  bottom: -47.63px;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 47px;
  height: 47px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 5px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  clip-path: circle(50%);
}

.slide .exit {
  animation: fadeInExit 4s forwards 7.5s;
}

@keyframes fadeInExit {
  99% {
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  100% {
    pointer-events: initial;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.exit::before,
.exit::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: red;
  width: 47px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: -5px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.exit::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.exit::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="curtain">
    <div class="ratio-keeper">

      <div class="wrap hide">
        <div class="video video-frame" data-id="CHahce95B1g"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel-left"></div>
      <div class="panel-right"></div>

    </div>
    <a href="https://www.google.com/">
      <div class="exit"></div>
    </a>

  </div>
  <button class="play" type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1r3576ey/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the image onto the panels that slide below the gradient.  Make the background width 200% and then align one to the right and one to the left:

```js
const manageCover = (function makeManageCover() {

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function hide(el) {
    el.classList.add("hide");
  }

  function openCurtain(cover) {
    hide(cover);
    const curtain = document.querySelector(".curtain");
    curtain.classList.add("slide");
    return curtain;
  }

  function showVideo(curtain) {
    const thewrap = curtain.parentElement.querySelector(".wrap");
    show(thewrap);
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    const curtain = openCurtain(cover);
    showVideo(curtain);
    cover.dispatchEvent(new Event("afterClick"));
  }

  function init(callback) {
    const cover = document.querySelector(".play");
    cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
    cover.addEventListener("afterClick", callback);
  }

  return {
    init
  };
}());

const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {
  let player;

  function loadIframeScript() {
    const tag = document.createElement("script");
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
  }

  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    const cover = document.querySelector(".play");
    const wrapper = cover.parentElement;
    const frameContainer = wrapper.querySelector(".video");
    addPlayer(frameContainer);
  }

  function onPlayerReady() {
    player.setVolume(100);
  }

  function addPlayer(video) {
    const options = {
      height: 360,
      host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
      videoId: video.dataset.id,
      width: 640
    };
    options.playerVars = {
      autoplay: 0,
      cc_load_policy: 0,
      controls: 1,
      disablekb: 1,
      fs: 0,
      iv_load_policy: 3,
      rel: 0
    };
    options.events = {
      "onReady": onPlayerReady
    };

    options.playerVars.loop = 1;
    options.playerVars.playlist = video.dataset.id;
    player = new YT.Player(video, options);
  }

  function play() {
    if (player && player.playVideo) {
      player.playVideo();
    }
  }

  function init() {
    player = null;
    loadIframeScript();
    window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = onYouTubeIframeAPIReady;
    return play;
  }

  return {
    init,
    play
  };
}());
manageCover.init(videoPlayer.init());
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(0, 0, 0) 0px, rgb(0, 0, 0) 10px, transparent 10px, transparent 11px), repeating-linear-gradient(22.5deg, rgb(0, 0, 0) 0px, rgb(0, 0, 0) 10px, transparent 10px, transparent 11px), linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(0, 89, 221), rgb(0, 89, 221), rgb(0, 89, 221), rgb(0, 89, 221), rgb(0, 89, 221));
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.curtain {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 640px;
  border: 21px solid;
  border-radius: 3.2px;
  border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
  position: relative;

}

.curtain::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  right: -2px;
  bottom: -2px;
  background: #0a0a0a;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
}

.curtain::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  outline: 1px solid #333;
  pointer-events: none;
}


.curtain.slide::after {
  outline: 1px solid #0059dd;
  transition: outline 2s ease-in;
  /*  add this */
  /*background-image: none;*/
}

.ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: fade 3s ease-in 0s forwards;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

iframe {
  user-select: none;
}

.panel-left,
.panel-right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0%;
  transition: all 8s ease;
  transition-delay: 4s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-left {
  left: 0;
  background: url("https://www.fillmurray.com/640/500") left top/200% auto no-repeat;
}

.panel-right {
  right: 0;
  background: url("https://www.fillmurray.com/640/500") right top/200% auto no-repeat;
}

/*.panel-left::before,
.panel-right::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  pointer-events: none;
}*/

.panel-left::before,
.panel-right::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  
  background:
    linear-gradient(45deg,
      transparent,
      transparent 7px,
      red 7px,
      red 7.5px,
      transparent 7.5px,
      transparent 10px),
    linear-gradient(-45deg,
      transparent,
      transparent 7px,
      red 7px,
      red 7.5px,
      transparent 7.5px,
      transparent 10px);
  background-size: 10px 10px;
  /* filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px #000);*/
  pointer-events: none;
}

.panel-right::before {
  left: -100%;
}

.curtain.slide .panel-left {
  transform: translateX(calc(-100% - 1px));
}

.curtain.slide .panel-right {
  transform: translateX(calc(100% + 1px));
}

.play {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 9px solid;
  background: transparent;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px #000000b3);
  animation: rotate 700ms linear forwards;
  border-color: red transparent red transparent;
    filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));

    color: #303030;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  99.9% {
    border-color: red transparent red transparent;
    pointer-events: none;
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    border-color: blue;
  }
}

.play::before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 27px solid;
  transform: translateX(4px);
  animation: triangle 700ms linear forwards;
}

@keyframes triangle {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  99.9% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    border-left-color: blue;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.play:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(43, 179, 20, 0.5);
}

.play:focus {
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.exit {
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  bottom: -47.63px;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 47px;
  height: 47px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 5px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  clip-path: circle(50%);
}

.slide .exit {
  animation: fadeInExit 4s forwards 7.5s;
}


@keyframes fadeInExit {
  99% {
    pointer-events: none;
  }

  100% {
    pointer-events: initial;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.exit::before,
.exit::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: red;
  width: 47px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: -5px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.exit::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.exit::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="curtain">
    <div class="ratio-keeper">

      <div class="wrap hide">
        <div class="video video-frame" data-id="CHahce95B1g"></div>

      </div>

      <div class="panel-left">
      </div>
      <div class="panel-right">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="https://www.google.com/">
      <div class="exit"></div>
    </a>

  </div>
  <button class="play" type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: How would this be written in long form? left top/200% auto no-repeat;

Comment: `background-position: left top; background-size: 200% auto; background-repeat: no-repeat;`

Comment: Can you see if you can help me figure this one out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74015913/how-would-i-go-about-setting-up-this-image-sprite

Comment: I don't think you can use a sprite for this - usually sprites are a combination of images so with this you are needing the image to be 200% the width of the box so it is split correctly.  If your sprite contains other images and is increased 200%, the split may not be in the correct place and then you have the hassle of trying to figure out where to position the image as it can no longer be top left and top right.

Comment: In this instance, it's best not to add this image to the sprite as there is no benefit from it, you are just increasing the sprite size massively (and reducing the quality of the image if you are changing what should be a jpg into a png) so you probably lose those few miliseconds your saving on that extra request anyway

Comment: This works: https://jsfiddle.net/cngk4vy7/3/