# How would I go about setting up this image sprite?

Tags: css, image, sprite

I am trying to set up an image sprite.

Using 2 image urls works: https://jsfiddle.net/xy0gsocf/1/

There should be a way to do this since I am able to with 2 image urls.

```
.panel-left {
  left: 0;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/xssQZZs.png");
  background-position: left top;
  background-size: 200% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.panel-right {
  right: 0;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/xssQZZs.png");
  background-position: right top;
  background-size: 200% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Here is my attempt at an **image sprite**.

https://jsfiddle.net/0e1okabt/1/

```
.panel-left,
.panel-right {
  left: 0;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/xssQZZs.png");
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.panel-right {
  right: 0;
  background-position: 0px -320px;
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I tried this: https://jsfiddle.net/0e1okabt/4/

```
.panel-left,
.panel-right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0%;
  transition: all 8s ease;
  transition-delay: 4s;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/xssQZZs.png");
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.panel-left{
  left: 0;
}

.panel-right {
  right: 0;
  background-position: 0px -320px;
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: you could just use a gradient if it is only about plain colors? https://jsfiddle.net/0gye2h8z/ or a single background-color:https://jsfiddle.net/0c83fgby/

Comment: No that won't work, needs to be an image sprite. I'm going to use a real image. The image sprite I made is being used as an example.

Comment: oky, so it is not plain colors ?

Comment: Correct........

Comment: you need to reset the `left:0` to `left:auto;` for the `.panel-right`. and `background-position` at : `top right` .

Comment: Can you show me it working in the code please?

Comment: possible example https://jsfiddle.net/vd4gum6x/

Comment: I changed it a little here: https://jsfiddle.net/cngk4vy7/3/